# Filter array returning not the elements of the array but the index numbers

Tags: arrays, dictionary, filter

```
let class_required = new Array("bad", 
                           "bad", "good", "bad", 
                           "good", "bad", "bad", 
                           "bad", "good");
```

I want to return only the elements that are "bad" but I want the index number returned, not bad hopefully using .filter or .map etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

The problem with `map` and `filter` is, for your usecase you have to use both and therefore iterate the array twice because

- `map` can only transform values, but not skip them. Ie the result will always contain a transformation for *all* values in the original array, not only the values you need.
- `filter` can only skip values, but not transform them. Ie the filtered array can only contain values, but not indexes.

You also have to apply them in correct order, because if you filter first (so you would have less values to transform) the indexes will be wrong.

```js
let class_required = new Array("bad", 
                           "bad", "good", "bad", 
                           "good", "bad", "bad", 
                           "bad", "good");
                           
let filtered = class_required.map((x,i) => x === "bad" ? i : -1)
                 .filter(x => x >=0)
console.log(filtered);
```

Or you can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for that, which allows you to transform your input array in whatever data structure you desire.

```js
let class_required = new Array("bad", 
                           "bad", "good", "bad", 
                           "good", "bad", "bad", 
                           "bad", "good");
                           
let filtered = class_required.reduce((a,c,i) => {
  if (c === "bad") a.push(i);
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(filtered);
```

Or you can, of course, also just use a simple for-loop (which will in fact be the functional equivalent of the `reduce` above)

```js
let class_required = new Array("bad", 
                               "bad", "good", "bad", 
                               "good", "bad", "bad", 
                               "bad", "good");
let filtered = [];
for (let i = 0; i < class_required.length; i++) {
  if (class_required[i] === "bad") {
    filtered.push(i);
  }
}
console.log(filtered);
```